# htaccess to convert controller/action to controller_action.html

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My .htaccess now is configured as:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

It works well as I access my controller/action. But now I need to access controller_action.html and get the same route. I cant find anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)_(.+)\.html$ /index.php?_url=/$1/$2 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The code above is for a one-time rewrite.

If you want to do it in 2 times (rewrite `/controller_action.html` to `/controller/action` which will be then rewritten to `/index.php?_url=/controller/action`)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)_(.+)\.html$ /$1/$2 [L]
```